# How to make data up to date on a shareable disk connected to KVM guest?

Tags: hard-drive, kvm-virtualization, share, virtio

I have 2 KVM guests running. One guest (let's call it the writing guest) writes to a virtio hdd (it's a lvm logical volume) periodically. Another guest (reading guest) reads from this disk (it's mounted to the reading guest in read-only mode) to do something else. The problem is when I change a file on the writing guest, it remains unchanged on the reading guest. The file is up to date only after manually remounting the disk on the reading guest.
I tried to mark the disk as shareable but that doesn't help.
How should I configure the disk keep the data up to date?
Sure I can just enable NFS and it will do the job, but I'm just wondering if there's a way to do it without NFS.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal file systems have no mechanism to support your desired mode of operation and the second VM will just not learn when the FS has changed.

The alternative would be to use a cluster-aware file system, but just using NFS will be *much* simpler.